# Black Screen ListView in dialogFragment Xamarin Android

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, android-dialogfragment, android-3.1-honeycomb

First the listview is GONE then it goes VISIBLE when i click a button but im having this error only in Mobile Devices with Android 3.1 the listview not showing. I try with the cachecolorhint #00000000 but its not working. Im currently developing with Xamarin.

Error Image:
http://i471.photobucket.com/albums/rr77/lithium1818/Android_20140924.png

C# Code:

```
 public void VisibilidadBloqueResultado(bool visible)
        {
            resultado.Visibility = visible == true ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
        }
```

After I set the listVisible I set de Adapter

```
adapter = new ListVisitaEmpresasAdapter(atx1, lista);
        empresas.Adapter = adapter;
        empresas.ItemClick += empresas_ItemClick;
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="300dip"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    p1:paddingTop="5dip"
    p1:paddingRight="5dip"
    p1:paddingBottom="5dip"
    p1:paddingLeft="5dip">
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="horizontal"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        p1:background="@color/portada">
        <TextView
            p1:text="Programar Visita"
            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            p1:layout_width="300dip"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/txt_titulo"
            p1:gravity="center_vertical"
            p1:paddingRight="10dip"
            p1:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            p1:paddingLeft="10dip"
            p1:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/scrollView1">
        <LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="vertical"
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
            p1:background="@color/fondo">
            <LinearLayout
                p1:orientation="vertical"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/Block_Descripcion">
                <WebView
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/web_content"
                    p1:minHeight="1dip" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                p1:orientation="vertical"
                p1:minWidth="25px"
                p1:minHeight="25px"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/lay_seleccion">
                <LinearLayout
                    p1:orientation="horizontal"
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
                    <TextView
                        p1:text="Ruta: "
                        p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                        p1:id="@+id/textView1"
                        p1:textColor="#000000"
                        p1:gravity="center_vertical"
                        p1:textStyle="bold" />
                    <Spinner
                        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                        p1:id="@+id/sp_zona" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    p1:orientation="vertical"
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    p1:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    p1:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
                    <EditText
                        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        p1:id="@+id/edt_buscar"
                        p1:hint="No. Cliente o Nombre " />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    p1:orientation="vertical"
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout7">
                    <Button
                        p1:text="Buscar"
                        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        p1:id="@+id/btn_search"
                        p1:layout_gravity="right"
                        p1:textColor="#000000"
                        p1:textStyle="bold"
                        p1:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                p1:orientation="vertical"
                p1:minWidth="25px"
                p1:minHeight="25px"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/lay_progress"
                p1:visibility="gone">
                <ProgressBar
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/progressBar1" />
                <TextView
                    p1:text="Obteniendo resultados..."
                    p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/textView2"
                    p1:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    p1:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="vertical"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/lay_resultados"
        p1:visibility="gone"
        p1:background="@color/fondocobranza">
        <LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="horizontal"
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout9">
            <Button
                p1:text="Modificar"
                p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                p1:id="@+id/btn_modificar"
                p1:textColor="#000000"
                p1:textStyle="bold" />
            <EditText
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                p1:id="@+id/edt_filter"
                p1:hint="Filtar resultados"
                p1:layout_marginLeft="3dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/list_empresas"
            p1:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's hard to help with no code and no xml you know?

Comment: I just post the XML code

Comment: Can you show us how are you setting the listview visibility to visible?

Comment: I just post the C# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just move the LinearLayout of the list before  the ScrollView and it works perfect here is the Final XML.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="300dip"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    p1:paddingTop="5dip"
    p1:paddingRight="5dip"
    p1:paddingBottom="5dip"
    p1:paddingLeft="5dip">
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="horizontal"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        p1:background="@color/portada">
        <TextView
            p1:text="Programar Visita"
            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            p1:layout_width="300dip"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/txt_titulo"
            p1:gravity="center_vertical"
            p1:paddingRight="10dip"
            p1:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            p1:paddingLeft="10dip"
            p1:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="vertical"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/lay_resultados"
        p1:background="@color/fondocobranza"
        p1:visibility="gone">
        <LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="horizontal"
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout9">
            <Button
                p1:text="Modificar"
                p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                p1:id="@+id/btn_modificar"
                p1:textColor="#000000"
                p1:textStyle="bold" />
            <EditText
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                p1:id="@+id/edt_filter"
                p1:hint="Filtar resultados"
                p1:layout_marginLeft="3dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/list_empresas"
            p1:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/scrollView1">
        <LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="vertical"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
            p1:background="@color/fondo">
            <LinearLayout
                p1:orientation="vertical"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/Block_Descripcion">
                <WebView
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/web_content"
                    p1:minHeight="1dip" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                p1:orientation="vertical"
                p1:minWidth="25px"
                p1:minHeight="25px"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/lay_seleccion">
                <LinearLayout
                    p1:orientation="horizontal"
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
                    <TextView
                        p1:text="Ruta: "
                        p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                        p1:id="@+id/textView1"
                        p1:textColor="#000000"
                        p1:gravity="center_vertical"
                        p1:textStyle="bold" />
                    <Spinner
                        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                        p1:id="@+id/sp_zona" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    p1:orientation="vertical"
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    p1:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    p1:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
                    <EditText
                        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        p1:id="@+id/edt_buscar"
                        p1:hint="No. Cliente o Nombre " />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    p1:orientation="vertical"
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout7">
                    <Button
                        p1:text="Buscar"
                        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        p1:id="@+id/btn_search"
                        p1:layout_gravity="right"
                        p1:textColor="#000000"
                        p1:textStyle="bold"
                        p1:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                p1:orientation="vertical"
                p1:minWidth="25px"
                p1:minHeight="25px"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/lay_progress"
                p1:visibility="gone">
                <ProgressBar
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/progressBar1" />
                <TextView
                    p1:text="Obteniendo resultados..."
                    p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/textView2"
                    p1:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    p1:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```